# Is it possible to use AWS Microsoft AD as one DC in a multi-master setup?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, domain-controller

Have an on-premise network with two AD servers already. Want to add one more AD server to the AWS cloud. Instead of setting up a Windows VM running AD, I'm wondering if I can use AWS Microsoft AD instead. It seems like it's full-fledged AD, and it would definitely do what I want in a cloud-only scenario, but I can't find explicit documentation on having it sync with other AD servers on the VPN.

Comment: Suggest you try it and see. I suspect it'll be fine. It's just Microsoft AD running in AWS, so open the right ports and it should work. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/active-directory-ds/scenario-2.html suggests something similar is possible, though I know this isn't full AD.

Comment: @Tim Yes, but that involves creating Windows VMs, which will obviously work but doesn't leverage AWS's Microsoft AD service.